# How to install Mod_Auth_Mellon with dependencies on Ubunto 16.10?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I've installed a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.10 and installed Apache2 and PHP on it according to this [site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04).
Next i wanted to install Mod_Auth_Mellon by the description on this [site](http://mkchendil.blogspot.de/2015/02/apache-and-openam-saml-federation.html).
Normally i should enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssl
$ sudo apt-get install pkg-config
$ sudo apt-get install libalsso3
$ sudo apt-get install libapachemod-auth-mellon
```

openssl is already installed.
pkg-config is installed correctly but the package libalsso3 cannot be found.

What has gone wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found it.
There are a few spelling mistakes on the site which i used.
The correct order is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install liblasso3
```